# Rails Application expecting me to restart my webrick server for any change in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on an existing Rails 2.3.x application, So I was working on it and it was a messy code with great difficulty I was able to run the application. But now for every small change in one of my controller it is expecting me to restart my serer otherwise the changes are not reflecting back, Let's take an example scenario here, Let's just say in one of the before_filter method I just added a puts statement on top of the method and it was not printing in the log, after I restart the server it is printing, Can some one please let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: This started happening to me today with Rails 3.1. My config.cache_classes = false but today I have to restart WEBrick every code change. Yesterday I didn't have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What environment are you using?

The default environment is 'development', where the code is reloaded on each request. However, this behaviour can be overwritten in the config file.

To be sure that the code is reloaded, add this into your `config/development.rb` file:

```
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false
```

Comment: Thanks vlad you saved me again :D, the cache_classes was set to true in development.rb (the env i was using). So I made it as false and it was working.

Comment: my `config/development.rb` have `config.cache_classes = false` but this won't help me out, I need to restart my server for Even a small change in my view, to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using config.threadsafe! It needs to be present before config.cache_classes=false as threadsafe makes cache_classes true again,  following link would make it more clear. [here](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have don't flush. The log system in Rails use a BufferedLogger. So need a flush to be print. Try a default logger.

Comment: thanks for the response shingara, I don't think this is the problem with logger, because lets just say there is some error in the line 50 of my application_controller and I commented the line to avoid error but i have to restart the server otherwise the application is getting error saying error at line 50 even though the line is not existing.