# Restart Rails server automatically after every change in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It should not be necessary to restart Rails server after any normal change. However, when I make little changes on my app controllers, they aren't applied if I don't restart the server. Even if I wrote bad code and made errors intentionally, the old error persists. How can I change that or verify that's well set up?

I have in `config/environment/development.rb file`:

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848063) didn't work for me.

UDPATE 1:

development.rb

```
    Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Comment: Which command using to start rails server and share your development.rb file content & try this in your terminal `export RAILS_ENV=development` and then restart your rails server.

Comment: I use: "rails s" to start my server. Where do I try this: "export RAILS_ENV=development"? Inside root application folder or anywhere?

Comment: just put it in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile file of the user you want to start the console with OR simply run it in your terminal right away it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I' running it with Windows 7. When I start server, it shows: "development".

Comment: Whenever I had to work with rails, I never had this issue. (I am on a Mac). What version of Rails are you using? Perhaps there is a bug specifically affecting windows.

Comment: Maybe It's a bug with Windows. I also had problems with installation. I could not install latest version. I had to install the penultimate stable version.

Comment: if you're using `require` to load files in your app, that can stop them from being unloadable .

Comment: @FrederickCheung, I don't use `require` for it.

Comment: Curiously, I created another app and It doesn't have the same problem. They a little different: in the problematic app, I wrote in routes.rb `namespace :api`. In the other, I don't use namespace because It didn't worked, but I don't have to restart after changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **nodemon** for auto restarting your old rails applications.

1) Install nodemon.

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

2) Create **nodemon.json** file  on root dir and configure it

```
{
  "ignore": [
    ".git",
    "node_modules/**/node_modules"
  ],
  "watch": [
    "app/controllers/",
    "app/models/",
    "app/assets/",
    "config/",
    "db/"
  ],
  "ext": "rb yml js css scss"
}
```

3) Create **rails.sh** file on root dir to start rails application using nodemon.

```
kill -9 `cat tmp/pids/server.pid`
echo "APP READY!!!"
echo "Ruby on Rails"
rails s -d
```

4) Give permission to `rails.sh` file.

```
sudo chmod +x rails.sh
```

5) Start server using `sh` command.

```
nodemon -L --exec "./rails.sh"
```

**Note: Steps verified on mac machine. different os may have different command or configuration.**